# xwiki - Get title of Page if rights are Read=False

Tags: velocity, xwiki

I'm trying to create an automatic Index where all the pages from the spaces will be displayed. Something like:

- Space 1 (public)

  - Page 1 (public)
  - Page 2 *(private)*

    - Page 2.1 (public)
- Space 2 (public)

  - Page A *(private)*
  - Page B (public)

Where:

- public: (Rights:`Read=True`) user can click to access the content.
- private: (Rights:`Read=False`) user can see the title but can't click.

If the user has no rights to `read` the page I want that at least he can get to see the title of the page as I can continue listing the pages that are able to `read` in the child.

What I have:

```
#foreach($space in $xwiki.spaces) 
    #set($WebHome = $space + ".WebHome")
    #getChildrenOf($WebHome)
#end
```

Now the recursive `getChildrenOf` macro is:

```
#macro(getChildrenOf, $docName)
    #foreach($name in $xwiki.searchDocuments('where doc.parent = ? or doc.parent = ? order by doc.name', [$docName, "xwiki:$docName"]))
         #if($xwiki.hasAccessLevel('view', "xwiki:$name"))
             [[$xwiki.getDocument($name).getPlainTitle()>>$name]]
         #else
             $xwiki.getDocument($name).getPlainTitle()
         #end
         #getChildrenOf($name)
    #end
#end
```

Results:

- In the `else`i'm getting a plain text showing the function `$xwiki.getDocument($name).getPlainTitle()` instead of the title of the Page.
- If I just write `$name` in the `else` what I get is: `Space_1.Page_2` instead of the title of Page 2.

Why is that happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xwiki.getDocument($name)` return null when the current user does not have view right on $name and when a method return null Velocity behavior is to display the code.

You can use `$xwiki.getDocumentAsAuthor($name)` instead to access the document with the right of the script's author. See http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/xwiki/platform/xwiki-platform-oldcore/6.2/xwiki-platform-oldcore-6.2-javadoc.jar/!/com/xpn/xwiki/api/XWiki.html#getDocumentAsAuthor%28org.xwiki.model.reference.DocumentReference%29